# Elasticsearch JSON API source - part missing?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

i'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeBytes(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1124)
at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._verifyValueWrite(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:984)
at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeNumber(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:797)
at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.util.JsonGeneratorDelegate.writeNumber(JsonGeneratorDelegate.java:266)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentGenerator.writeNumber(JsonXContentGenerator.java:114)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.value(XContentBuilder.java:981)
at TreMVN.DNM.App.main(App.java:174)
```

to "line-174" of the following:

```
    XContentBuilder o = response.getFromContext("3");   
    o.contentType();
    o.value(75);  // line-174
```

`response` here is of type `org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse` and 
`org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder` is the type of `o`.

why this error?

//-------------------

in another line - the source of the package `org.elasticsearch.common.jackson` didn't "come out of the box". it's not in [Javadocs](http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/v1.5.2/) either.

what am i missing ???

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

org.elasticsearch.common.jackson is a repackage of jackson library to avoid package name collision

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/UTF8JsonGenerator.java

Comment: is there a way to integrate the source into the project so that i can see it in my Eclipse development environment? i'm merely looking to be able to navigate to these JSON sources when i'm coding.

Comment: The source jar (http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/1.7.0/elasticsearch-1.7.0-sources.jar)  distributed by Elastic does not include the shaded dependencies. You will need to modify the pom https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/pom.xml to include shaded dependency in the source jar https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-1573